# Can't set header using Github API from Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, github-api

I'm using javascript's XMLHttpRequest to receive data from Github API and I am trying to use the [custom media type](https://developer.github.com/v3/media/) specification but can't get it to work. Setting the `Accept` header doesn't change the format of the response at all. The result I get is always the default (JSON).

This is the code I'm using to make the request:

```
var url = "https://api.github.com/repos/mrdoob/three.js/issues/comments/241553390";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3.raw");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/vnd.github.v3.raw");
xhr.onload = function(ev) {
    console.log("Response:", ev.target.response);
    console.log("Headers:", xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
};
xhr.send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response JSON contains a "body" attribute.

I tried changing the version from raw to other types and noticed that only the "body" attribute changes. Did I understand your question wrong? What other types of response does GitHub API support?
`xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3.html");` results in `"body_html"` while `xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3.html");` results in `"body"`

JSFiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/3yqutj29/4/

Comment: I didn't expect only one attribute of the response to change, but that makes sense and solved my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting comments, which are all returned as JSON which you can use the media type to specify the body markdown. See: https://developer.github.com/v3/media/#comment-body-properties

The `application/vnd.github.v3.raw` is used for requesting a binary blob.